# Jetpack Compose Text Show Confuse

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

if code like this:

```
Text(
    "Text with background",
    Modifier.drawBackground(Color.Magenta, RectangleShape).padding(10.dp)
)
```

[image: first drawBackground second do padding]

```
Text(
    "Text with background",
    Modifier.padding(10.dp).drawBackground(Color.Magenta, RectangleShape)
)
```

[image: first do padding second drawBackground]

jetpack compose config

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerVersion "1.3.70-dev-withExperimentalGoogleExtensions-20200424"
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "0.1.0-dev10"
}

implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-framework:0.1.0-dev10'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-layout:0.1.0-dev10'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-material:0.1.0-dev10'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-tooling:0.1.0-dev10'
```

Comment: Your two code snippets seem to be identical.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The order of modifiers are important in Jetpack compose
to make it visible I wrapped it inside a parent with gray background:

```kotlin
Column {
    // It just draws a background with out any padding
    Stack(modifier = Modifier.drawBackground(Color.Gray)) {
        Text(
            "Order of modifiers are important",
            Modifier.drawBackground(Color.Magenta, RectangleShape)
        )
    }

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

    // In this one we put the padding modifier before the drawBackground
    // It first adds a padding, what should be the color of that padding?
    // so far we didn't tell any thing about it to Jetpack compose so it's transparent
    // and shows the color of parent layout that's gray color
    // then draws the background behind the content of Text(but doesn't change the color of padding)
    Stack(modifier = Modifier.drawBackground(Color.Gray)) {
        Text(
            "Order of modifiers are important",
            Modifier.padding(10.dp).drawBackground(Color.Magenta, RectangleShape)

        )
    }

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

    // In this one we put the padding modifier after the drawBackground
    // It first draws a background behind the text
    // then padding applies but this time it's not transparent, it inherits the color of
    // backgroundColor
    Stack(modifier = Modifier.drawBackground(Color.Gray)) {
        Text(
            "Order of modifiers are important",
            Modifier.drawBackground(Color.Magenta, RectangleShape).padding(10.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: cooool, Thank you very much for your reply, I've been following the profile as I understood it before and it seems that the order of the modifiers does have an effect on the results and the default is a reasonable behavior. I think the order of the configuration should have no effect on the result if the code is understood in terms of configuration items, similar to the builder design pattern.